# Error running 'app': The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_31 has terminated

Tags: android

I am a college student taking an Android app programming class this semester... I have to set it up in advance using the Android studio before class. There's a problem. AVD is not running. "Error running 'app': The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_31 has terminated." showed up. After googling, I found SEVERE errors in idea text documents through the menu in Help-show login Explorer. The error is as follows.

> 2023-09-06 08:39:14,841 [ 561211] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - Cannot create com.intellij.psi.PsiManager because container is already disposed (container=Project(name=My_Application, containerState=DISPOSE_COMPLETED, componentStore=C:\ProjectFolder) (disposed))
> com.intellij.serviceContainer.AlreadyDisposedException: Cannot create com.intellij.psi.PsiManager because container is already disposed (container=Project(name=My_Application, containerState=DISPOSE_COMPLETED, componentStore=C:\ProjectFolder) (disposed))
> at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ContainerUtilKt.throwAlreadyDisposedError(containerUtil.kt:40)
> at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:695)
> at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:629)
> at com.intellij.psi.PsiManager.getInstance(PsiManager.java:25)
> at com.intellij.ide.todo.CurrentFileTodosPanel.setFile(CurrentFileTodosPanel.java:54)
> at com.intellij.ide.todo.CurrentFileTodosPanel$1.lambda$selectionChanged$0(CurrentFileTodosPanel.java:46)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:74)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:114)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:36)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:788)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:758)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:756)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
> 2023-09-06 08:39:14,841 [ 561211] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1  Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
> 2023-09-06 08:39:14,841 [ 561211] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
> 2023-09-06 08:39:14,841 [ 561211] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.FlushQueue - OS: Windows 11

Please... help me...

Cold Boot now, Wipe data, Check AVD way, Check SDK Manager(Installed all), Reinstalling...